# The relation between the movement of electrons and energy

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, field-theory

So, I've been enjoying reading a lot of helpful posts, but now, I found myself in the need of asking something.

I have a hard time grasping the general concept of electricity / how the relation between the movement of electrons and energy corresponds.

But so far I've reach this conclusion / guess:

1) The movement of electrons, should rather be called mechanical energy, than calling it electric energy.

Why?

Electrons move by pushing to each other, typical mechanical energy example. That electrons has a electric charge, doesn't make the movement of them electric energy.

2) Every single electron has their own electric field. When there is a potential difference between minus and plus (electroncurrent), we say that there will be created an uniform field, because of the field lines between two parallel conducting plates with oppositely charges.  Meanwhile, when electrons move in the same direction, they create a magnetic field.

**And now comes my guess:**

My statement: It is the effects of the magnetic and electric field in the wire, that do the work on electronic devices.

We know that fields of all kinds can exert a force on any given object within its reach. So my guess is that this electromagnetic field the wire creates, can effect: a smaller wire in a computer, the wires that goes to the screen, the way the screen lights up. So you could say that the energy / what I would believe people in general thinks is 'electricity' exists not only inside the wire, but also outside.

So when a device is 'using' / 'transforming' the energy to other energyforms, you could think of it this way.

1) Remembering that a current exists in a closed circuit.
2) When you exert a force from a battery or whatever, the electrons move very slowly themselves, but all in all as a system, they move at the speed of light. When they do this, the electromagnetic field will be a natural follower of this event.

So when we transform energy/ use energy, it is the constant need for making the electrons move around, in order to create the electromagnetic field. And when there is no force to push the electrons around, the electromagnetic field disappears - and no work is done, and no money spent.

This would also mean / or be the reasoning behind why devices / light or what so ever, starts in splitseconds. Because the electromagnetic field comes at the speed of light, because the electrons move the way they do. And using the expressions as potential energy, is just a way of saying that you create a strong difference between minus and plus (electroncurrent.) And the electromagneticfield will be "tapped" when there is devices nearby, but the current logically remains the same, buut, the electromagnetic field will be weaker near plus, because it has already done a lot of work. But we might be taking about fractions of seconds, so we probably wouldn't register it.. (is this right or just totally wrong reasoning??)

So saying electricity, could in daily life relate to:

the movement of electrons

or

the effects of electromagnetic field exertion on electronic devices.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when they are pushed in the same direction, they create what we call an uniform electric field

Movement of electrons in the same direction does not create a uniform electric field.  Two infinite parallel plates with an electric potential difference between them, and no movement of electrons or other charged particles, would set up a uniform electric field therebetween.

Comment: Okay, I understand. The electric potential difference is created because of the force that creates the difference between minus and plus (electroncurrent). My fault to say that the electrons created the uniform field, instead it is the field lines between two parallel conducting plates with oppositely charges.
I would still like to hear about the other thoughts I wrote.

Thank you.

Comment: A moving electron has kinetic energy.  An arrangement of charges has potential energy. The potential energy is due to the electromagnetic force, one of the 4 fundamental forces along with gravitation and the strong and weak forces.   For example, two electrons that are 1 nanometer apart have a different potential energy than two electrons 1 meter apart.  Moving a charge through an electrical potential involves work.  It takes work to put two electrons closer together.  Two electrons allowed to move apart can do work.